# Librería Data-Binding + Navigation Drawer

Tags: java, android, binding

Estoy haciendo un app, estoy tratando de seguir la documentación oficial de la [librería](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/index.html) la misma funciona bien en una actividad normal.

El asunto es que mi actividad es un NavigationDrawerActivity o bueno estoy usando la ayuda de Android Studio 3.1 para crear la Actividad. Al intentar implementar la librería la interfaz se cambia.

Es decir lo que quiero es usar la librería Data-Binding y conservar el app visualmente sin cambios. Mi problema es que inicialmente agregue el código del binding en el archivo content_login.xml y el resultado fue que se pierde el topBar y el menú desplegable (NavigationDrawer).
Lo cambie luego al activity_login.xml y fue muy similar solo que esta vez me conservó el topbar pero no los botones MenuItem... Decidí entonces carbiar el código y hacerlo en app_bar_login.xml y me dió el mismo resultado.

**Resultados:**
Con código en app_bar_login.xml
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Con código en activity_login.xml
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Objetivo visual al que quiero llegar con binding**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Android Studio crea el siguiente árbol de carpetas y archivos:
[image: Mi estructura de proyecto]

El código en la clase Java:

```
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);



        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

        ContentLoginBinding binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.content_login);
        binding.setUsuario(new Usuario("USUARIO_PRUEBA", "123456"));


        /*AppBarLoginBinding binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.app_bar_login);
        binding.setUsuario(new Usuario("USUARIO_PRUEBA", "123456"));*/

    }
}
```

Los xml agregan la etiqueta `<Layout>` y `<Data>` y `<variable>`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout >
    <data>
        <variable
            name="usuario"
            type="com.labs.examples.ejemplosaveroompersistence.Usuario" />
    </data>

    <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        tools:context="com.labs.examples.ejemplosaveroompersistence.LoginActivity"
        tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_login"

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">


        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="Usuario"
                android:inputType="text"
                android:text="@{usuario.usuario}"/>
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="Clave"
                android:inputType="textPassword"
                android:text="@{usuario.clave}"/>
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
</layout>
```

Comment: ¿lograste solucionarlo? tengo el mismo problema: son data binding todo OK pero con data binding se pierde el toolbar y el navigation drawer.

Comment: Si lo logré y justamente eso que mencionas me sucedía. Déjame ver si encuentro el proyecto y paso la respuesta que usé Igualmente puedes publicar la pregunta y esperar que alguien más ayude.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inicialmente el databiding se habilita en el archivo `build.gradle (Module:app)`
de la siguiente manera:

```
android{
     ....
     dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }
}
```

Se reemplaza el `setContentView(R.layout.activity_login)` por

```
ActivityloginBinding binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(this, R.layout.activity_login);
```

La variable binding se puede declarar globalmente ya que esta tiene cada elemento(componente) del xml que se va a enlazar con la clase.

Para la parte de asignación para no hacer una respuesta muy larga prefiero revisar la documentación oficial de Android sobre [expresiones](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/expressions) y sobre [observers](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/observability)

link databinding